# SVGZ gives encoding error

Tags: svg

I'm sitting here using SVG, and I would like to gzip those files, using the SVGZ - The problem is, that I get this error when I open the SVGZ file:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error Below is a rendering of
>   the page up to the first error.

I've tried creating the same svg in different types of applications, and tried it in different browsers and even servers. I've worked with svgz before, where I could get it showing, but it was some time ago..

Anyone that knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found making sure the 'Image Location' is set to '[image]Embed' and NOT 'link' in the saving to SVG settings worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and i found the solution after some digging.
My solution is for IIS but during my test i found the same behavior on Apache.

Mime type for svgz is somewhat bugged, because is the same of uncompressed SVG:

```
image/svg+xml
```

So to enable SVGZ serving on IIS i had to add a rewrite rule which added the hedaer

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

This was working but sometimes the browser was receiving the former encoding error.

The problem was the server treated svgz as static content, and because "static compression" was enabled on the site, the client were receiving sometimes the original content, sometimes the compressed (and cached) one, without knowing the difference because server compression act enabling the gzip Content-Encoding header, the same the rewrite rule was enabling all the times.

The client is actually unable to understand when the server re-compressed the content and when not.

The possible solutions are:

- disable static compression at all
- disable static compression MIME Mapping for image/svg+xml mime type. This will disable compression for svg too, but if your site serve only svgz, this won't be an issue.

The second solution for IIS can be enabled editing applicationHost.config:

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
            <...>
            <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

Hope this will help you.

PS: this is my first post on stackoverflow!

Comment: This helped me. You can also disable static compression for a specific folder (at least in a virtual directory) via IIS if you look for Compression section after selecting the specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess from the information you are providing but it looks as if you are sending gzipped SVG without having properly set Content-Encoding: gzip. That will cause the browser's XML parser to fail to parse the content, since it won't be XML.

Comment: I found the solution, I exported the svg in illustrator, opened it in my texteditor, removed the encoding="utf-8" saved, converted the svg to svgz, and it did work. So because of the utf-8 encoding it didn't work :/